# Is there any other way to do this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to check if a player's XP is a certain amount, it will change the player's rank.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Here is the code:

currentLevelText.text = currentLevel;

```
    if (currentLevel == "Rookie")
        xp += Random.Range(3, 10);
    else if (currentLevel == "Survivor")
        xp += Random.Range(5, 12); 
    else if (currentLevel == "Adventurer")
        xp += Random.Range(7, 14); 
        
    // Please send help 
    if (xp <= 0 || xp ==   1 || xp ==  2 || xp == 3 || 
        xp == 4 || xp == 5 ||xp ==  6 || xp == 7 || xp == 8 ||
        xp == 9 || xp == 10 ||xp ==  11 || xp == 12 || xp == 13 || xp == 14 || 
        xp == 15 || xp == 16 || xp == 17 || xp == 18 || xp == 19 || xp ==  20 || xp == 
         21 
        || xp == 22 || xp == 23 || xp == 24) 
        
        currentLevel = "Rookie";
    
    
    else if (xp == 25 || xp == 26 || xp == 27 || xp == 28 || xp == 29 || xp == 30 )  
        currentLevel = "Survivor";
    
    else if (xp == 31 || xp == 32 || 
             xp == 33 || xp == 34 || xp == 35 
             || xp == 36 || xp == 37 || xp == 38 ||
             xp == 39 || xp == 40)
        
        currentLevel = "Adventurer";
    else if (xp < 100) {
        currentLevel = "Veteran"; 
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: `xp <= 0`  - you're alread doing the neccessary thing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment sir, but that operator indicates that if the xp is less than or equal to 0. But I want to check if the XP is (i.e.) 30 TO 40, change the player level.

Comment: so in other words... you want to check if it is _greater than 30 AND less or equal to 40_....?

Comment: yes sir. thank you.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). also: there's no need to call me (or anyone here) sir. and maybe [the dotnet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/) will be helpful to you.

Comment: I recommend declaring an `enum` for the rank so you don't have to deal with repeated strings and the bugs that might occur with a typo.

Comment: **Please come up with a (better) title for your question ...**

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to start out by understanding what [`<` and `>` and `<=` and `>=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators) do. You don't need to check for every possible case of the integer value, just the range. You can likely accomplish this with a method like this:

```
    public string GetLevel(int xp)
    {
        if (xp <= 24) return "Rookie";
        if (xp <= 30) return "Survivor";
        if (xp <= 40) return "Adventurer";
        return "Veteran";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As seen in other answers you should write a function that calculates the rank from the `xp` value.

```
/// <summary>
/// Define the rank from the given xp.
/// </summary>
public static PlayerRank GetRankFromXp(int xp)
{
    // Novice: 1..15
    if (xp>0 && xp < 16) return PlayerRank.Novice;
    // Rookie: 16..23
    if (xp < 24) return PlayerRank.Rookie;
    // Survivor: 24..29
    if (xp < 30) return PlayerRank.Survivor;
    // Adventurer: 30..39
    if (xp < 40) return PlayerRank.Adventurer;
    // Veteran: 40..99
    if (xp < 100) return PlayerRank.Veteran;
    // God: >=100
    if (xp >= 100) return PlayerRank.God;
    // None: =0
    return PlayerRank.None;
}
```

but what is `PlayerRank` above? It is an [**`enum`**](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_enums.php) which associates a name with some constant value.

```
public enum PlayerRank
{
    None,
    Novice,
    Rookie,
    Survivor,
    Adventurer,
    Veteran,
    God,
}
```

This way you don't have to deal with string values and accidentally trying to compare `"Rookie"` to `"Rokie"` or any other typo that might show up.

In addition to the above you should make a function that returns some random `xp` value based on the rank. This would be an excellent place for a [**`switch()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_switch.php) statement that checks against specific ranks.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a random amount of xp based on the rank.
/// </summary>
public static int RandomXp(PlayerRank rank)
{
    switch (rank)
    {
        case PlayerRank.Novice:
            return Random.Range(1, 8);
        case PlayerRank.Rookie:
            return Random.Range(3, 10);
        case PlayerRank.Survivor:
            return Random.Range(5, 12);
        case PlayerRank.Adventurer:
            return Random.Range(7, 14);
        case PlayerRank.Veteran:
            return Random.Range(9, 16);
        case PlayerRank.God:
            return Random.Range(11, 20);
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

and some sample usage of the above would be in the function `LevelUp()` below:

```
public class Player
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Player"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Player()
    {
        Xp = 0;
        Rank = PlayerRank.None;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the xp.
    /// </summary>
    public int Xp { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the player rank.
    /// </summary>
    public PlayerRank Rank { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Levels up the player.
    /// </summary>
    public void LevelUp()
    {
        Xp += RandomXp(Rank);
        Rank = GetRankFromXp(Xp);
    }

}
```

<sub>Note that when displaying an `enum` on the screen it automatically converts the name into the corresponding characters. For example `PlayerRank.Novice.ToString() => "Novice"`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if-else block instead.

```
            if (xp <= 24 )
                currentLevel = "Rookie";
            else if (xp<=30)
                currentLevel = "Survivor";
            else if (xp<=40)
                currentLevel = "Adventurer";
            else                
                currentLevel = "Veteran";
```

there is no need to check each individual value, and there is no need to check previous conditions if you are in an "else" clause

Comment: Thank you sir, you are very helpful. Although I would like to check if the xp integer is 24 upto 30

Comment: @LeoMehta it's already doing that ... `xp <= 24` is true for **anything smaller than or equal to 24** ... if this is not the case it checks the next condition which is **anything smaller than or equal to 30** .. so 25-30 ... etc

Answer (score 0):

After having read and understood [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70084639/7111561) you can also use a [relational pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#relational-patterns) which does basically the same thing just reads different

```
public string GetLevel(int xp)
{
    return xp switch
    {
        <= 24 => "Rookie",
        <= 30 => "Survivor",
        <= 40 => "Adventurer",
        _ => "Veteran"
    };
}
```

Also an `enum` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086082/7111561) will be way better then using strings!